# javascript loop and calling soap webservice

Tags: javascript, loops, soap, xml-parsing

I'm calling a web service in a loop and pass parameter from the DB to the web service.All the web service call gets a response in a loop.Here is my response XML nodes [Siebel response][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRCE2.png

My existing code is

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

for(db=0;db.length;db++) // db loop
{
//call webservice and get below is **employeeData is multiple soap webservice response** xml that is attached in the picture. 

var soapEnv = new Namespace("SOAP-ENV","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
var rpc = new Namespace("http://siebel.com/asi/");

var siebelMessage = **employeeData**.soapEnv::Body.rpc::STEMIServiceRequestThinRefreshResponse.SiebelMessage;
    default xml namespace = "http://www.siebel.com/xml/STE%20MI%20Service%20Request%20Thin%20Refresh";
var employee = siebelMessage.ListOfSteMIServiceRequestThinRefresh.ListOfServiceRequest["ServiceRequest"];
for each(var rootNodeVal in employee) {

// do parsing but it executes only the first response and exits any advice
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Siebel side ListOfServiceRequest is a literally List of Zero(One) or More ServiceRequests. 
And

```
for each(var rootNodeVal in employee)
```

Incorrect in this case, because every rootNodeVal=ServiceRequest. Consider common loop (as example)
`for (var i =0; i < count; i++){
       ListOfServiceRequest[i] ....
}`